# FocusNavigationDirection.Next is not moving to Next Control

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid, focus

```
TraversalRequest request = new TraversalRequest(FocusNavigationDirection.Next);                    
MoveFocus(request);
```

I am using this code in DataGrid PreviewKeyDown Event and the Focus is not moving to Next Control instead its focus has gone to Two Control previous to DataGrid.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use this code for request :

```
TraversalRequest request = new TraversalRequest(FocusNavigationDirection.Down);
```

use **Down** for request
hope helpfull